# ¿como capturar el valor de un checkbox sin usar un formulario y pasar ese valor como parámetro?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, blazor

hola comunidad tengo una duda como puedo capturar el valor de un checkbox sin usar un formulario, quiero capturar el valor simplemente seleccionando el checkbox una vez teniendo el valor pasarlo como parámetro aun método el cual llama a endpoint en un controlador

este es mi checkbox toggle en el cual quiero capturar su valor:

```
<input id="toggle-one" data-onstyle="info" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Enabled" data-off="Disabled">
```

este es el método al cual le quiero pasar el valor capturado en el checkbox:

```
   protected async Task GetXml(bool filtro)
    {       
        var responseHttp = await repositorio.Get<PaginadorGenerico<Comprobante>>($"api/Xml?filtro={filtro}");       
        var resultado = responseHttp.Response.Resultado;       
        Comprobante = (List<Comprobante>)resultado;
    }
```

y esta es solo una parte del controlador el cual recibirá el parámetro enviado por el método:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<PaginadorGenerico<Comprobante>>> Get(bool filtro,string buscar, int pagina,
                                                                                 string orden = "Rfc",
                                                                                 string tipo_orden = "ASC",                                                                                 
                                                                                 int registros_por_pagina = 10)
        {
            List<Comprobante> _Xml;
            PaginadorGenerico<Comprobante> _PaginadorFacturas;                     
            _Xml = db.XMLs.Find(_ => true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes definir el evento [`onchange`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1) del *checkbox*.

Una de las formas más sencillas de afrontar este escenario sería mantener una propiedad en la *view* para luego usarla en tu método `GetXml`, en vez de pasarlo por parámetro.

```
<input id="toggle-one" type="checkbox" @onchange="e => CheckChanged(e)">

@code 
{
    bool _checked = false;

    void CheckChanged(ChangeEventArgs ev)
    {
        _checked = (bool)ev.Value; // Guardamos el valor
    }

    // ...

    async Task GetXml()
    {
        // En la llamada ya no usas el parámetro filtro sinó la propiedad _checked.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: hola gracias por la ayuda, estoy probando tu código a que te refieres con propiedad en el view ?

Comment: La propiedad en la *view* es `_checked`.

Comment: al darle clic al check se queda su valor en false no me cambia a true

Comment: ¿Pones un *breakpoint* dentro de `CheckChanged` y no para? Porque acabo de reproducir el ejemplo y me funciona.

Comment: en consola al dar clic si me muestra true y false , pero al enviarlo al controlador aunque este en true se envía como false

Comment: ¿Estás usando la nueva propiedad para llamar al repositorio? Si pones un *breakpoint* en `GetXml`, ¿el valor de `_checked` es el que debería?

Comment: ya funciono muchas gracias por tu tiempo y ayuda, el problema era al cargar la pagina de blazor al cargarla por primera vez tomaba el valor false y al dar clic en el checkbox si cambiaba al true , pero ya no se recargaba la pagina para actualizar los datos cuando es true